# Подскажите на каком движке сделать CRM

Tags: php

Поставили задачу создания CRM по типу, прием просмотр заказов. Заказы будут приходить с одностраничников. Есть готовые crm или луче взять движок и пилить под свои нужды (какой движок луче использовать под такие нужды). Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно такие CRM на php пишут на своем* движке, то есть такие crm как `vtiger crm` и `sugarcrm` имеют свои "движки", но ничто не мешает на их основе создать свою crm. То есть вы можете создать свою CRM на базе любой другой open source crm системы. Рекомендую обратить внимание на `SugarCRM` и `VTigerCRM` ниже ссылки. Эти CRM с открытым кодом. Также если писать код с ноля можно использовать фреймворки такие как `Symfony` или `Laravel` (и другие). Ниже ссылки.

http://www.sugarcrm.com/download

http://www.vtiger.ru

http://www.symfony-project.org

https://laravel.com